# jQuery Mobile - adding list of checkbox dynamically

Tags: jquery-mobile

i'm trying to add a list of checkbox dynamically but it does not show properly with mobile style.

here the js code:

```
var name = "option";
var id = "id";

$("#frame").html('<fieldset data-role="controlgroup"><legend>Seleziona le categorie da eliminare:</legend></fieldset>');

for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  $("fieldset").append('<input type="checkbox" name="' + name + '" id="' + id + '"><label for="' + name + '">' + name + '</label>');
}

$("#frame").append('<a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" id="btndelcat">Elimina</a>');

$("#frame").trigger('create');
```

[Code](http://jsfiddle.net/xb9kL/) on editor JSFiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a mistake in creating checkboxes. Label's `for` attribute should match checkbox's `id`.

From this:

```
$("fieldset").append('<input type="checkbox" name="' + name + '" id="' + id + '"><label for="' + name + '">' + name + '</label>');
```

To this:

```
$("fieldset").append('<input type="checkbox" name="' + name + '" id="id' + i + '"><label for="id' + i + '">' + name + '</label>');
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/NrwGg/)**